# Popup Placement In Some Laptops

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

as you see in following code. I create a popup one time with child and other time without child.

the problem is they open in different places.

note: this happens in some laptops(PC) not all of them.

my laptop = ZenBook model:UX303L (Windows 8.1)

[image: Popup Placement]

my code:

```
 public MainWindow()
 {

     InitializeComponent();
     CreatePopup(true);
     CreatePopup(false);
 }

 private void CreatePopup(bool haveChild)
 {
     Popup popup = new Popup();
     popup.Width = 200;
     popup.Height = 200;
     popup.HorizontalOffset = 500;
     popup.VerticalOffset = 50;

     if (haveChild)
     {
         var tb = new TextBlock() { Text = "TextBlock1", Background =          
                                  Brushes.Yellow, Width = 200, Height = 200 };
         tb.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
         popup.Child = tb;
     }

     popup.StaysOpen = true;
     popup.IsOpen = true;
 }
```

Comment: The resolution is different on different laptops...

Comment: @Alex I run the program in my own laptop and the result was above picture